# Is this function logical or am I over thinking? Loop errors for finding even number

Tags: python

> Which code segment should replace the statement **pass** in the function hasEvenNumber which returns True if n contains an even number and False otherwise?

```
def hasEvenNumber(n):
    for i in n:
        pass # Replace this section with below options
    return result
```

[The question screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbsAZ.png)

This is an actual university exam question. I find it very badly structured and since my classmates are new too, nobody dared to voice out fearing to make a fool of themselves.

Firstly n was not given, but judging that n will be used in a for loop. n therefore, would be an iterable. I think none of the 4 options applies, but please advise me if I'm wrong.

**Option 1:**

```
if i % 2 == 0:
    result = True
else:
    result = False
```

This will only work if iterable only contains 1 item e.g [1,2,1] will not work since the result of 2 as even number that should return true will be replaced as the loop proceed to next iteration.

```
[1,2,1,1] False # Wrong, should be true
[1,1,1,2] True
      [2] True
```

**Option 2:**

```
if i % 2 == 0:
    result = True
    break
else:
    result = False
    break
```

Worse than above, this will only iterate the first item and break regardless.

```
[1,2,1,1] False # Wrong, should be true
[1,1,1,2] False  # Wrong, should be true
      [2] True
```

**Option 3:**

```
if i % 2 == 0:
    result = True
    break
```

Function will have runtime error if no even number is found, the variable result will not be assigned.

```
[1,2,1,1] True
[1,1,1,1] Runtime Error
      [2] True
      [1] Runtime Error
```

**Option 4:**

```
if i % 2 != 0:
    result = False
    break
```

Same as above, runtime error. No variable will be assigned if all even numbers.

Personally, as the question asked to check if n contains even number. I would have written something like this.

```
# Break and exit loop once even number is found. Otherwise continue.
if i % 2 == 0:
    result = True
    break
else:
    result = False
```

Unfortunately, this is not an option. Apologies if this is the wrong place to post this, but any advice would be gladly appreciated, and could possibly change the fate our my current school cohort.

Comment: After discussing with fellow schoolmates. The opinions were quite torn on option 3 to just assume False is pre-assigned to result.

Most arguably, many said that we do not just automatically assume something is assigned as this is potentially dangerous in many other contexts. 

Many were wondering if this question is just erroneous in nature to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right and little bit overthinking.

Third option is right and it is kinda assumed here that `result` is set to `False` in the beginning.

Also, your solution can be optimised by declaring `result = False` once in the beginning and then you can eliminate the `else` block completely.

Comment: The school will explicitly mention if assumptions are predefined. our worst fear is to put assumptions in by ourselves and get penalized.

Comment: Yes, you can mention this as well. Other options are logically wrong except 3rd. So if you can't mention any assumption, I would suggest you go with logical correct answer.

Comment: I would agree with making that assumption. although most of the students are quite horrified since there are lots of questions in the exam that has ambiguity like the above. 
I feel that it would be a very bad introduction to programming and practice to make convenient assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to end when an even number is found, option 3.

Comment: Appreciate your input, but option 3 does not return False and will produce Runtime Error if number is not found.